Proper System Message Construction in Chatbot
I have 3 statements as my SystemMessages. The second one is not working. What might be the possible reason and fix?
    chatBotService.CustomSystemMessages([
      new (<systemmessage1>,, false),
      new ("If the input query is trying to end the conversation such as 'thanks', 'thank you', 'bye' or any same meaning, add this link 'httxps://xax.org/xax' in the response for user feedback. ", false),
      new (<systemmessage3>, false)

]);
